# Hide Show/Hide button for group rows in NSOutlineView

Tags: swift, macos, appkit, nsoutlineview

My NSOutlineView has some group rows that cannot be collapsed, similar to Mail.app's inability to hide the "Mailboxes" group. I would expect the Show/Hide hover button to be disabled if the delegate's `shouldCollapseItem` method returns `false`, but that seems to not be the case.

I've tried manually disabling it with the following delegate:

```
func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, willDisplayOutlineCell cell: Any, for tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, item: Any) {
    if outlineView.delegate?.outlineView?(outlineView, shouldCollapseItem: item) == false {
        if let view = outlineView.delegate?.outlineView?(outlineView, viewFor: tableColumn, item: item) {
            if let button = view.subviews.first(where: { $0.identifier == NSOutlineView.showHideButtonIdentifier }) {
                button.isHidden = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work, since the view that is returned is just the `NSTableCellView` that will be rendered, and it doesn't have a superview at the time this delegate is called (so I can't look for sibling views).

I can access the Show/Hide button (which is an undocumented `NSOutlineButtonCell` instance) in the `makeView(withIdentifier:owner:)` delegate, but at this point I don't know if it will be representing one of the groups that can hidden or not.

There's got to be a way to do it, since Mail.app (and other apps) are able to conditionally disable the group's Show/Hide button.

Comment: You are strongly discouraged from calling delegate methods containing `did`, `will`, `should` and even `outlineView(viewFor`. Don't do that. Those methods are exclusively called by the framework.

Comment: Great advice. And in any case, as I pointed out, it doesn't work. Hence my original question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Implement

```
func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, shouldShowOutlineCellForItem item: Any) -> Bool
```

and return `false` for the cells to be hidden

Comment: That worked! The docs say that it only affects the disclosure triangle, but I guess the Show/Hide button is equivalent to the triangle.